# possible bug in typescript JQuery.html()

Tags: jquery, typescript

example:

```
let $div = $("div");
let $p = $("p");
$div.html($p);
```

gives this error:

Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

**EDIT:**
in plain js/jquery this is working. An equivalent (in final result) to the following (still in typescript):

```
let $div = $("div");
let $p = $("p");
$div.html("").append($p);
```

Does the typescript definition of `JQuery.html()` is wrong or did i made a mistake somewhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature that you are looking for is missing in typescript definition (as it is not documented), but you can add it manually:

```
interface JQuery{
    html(obj:JQuery): JQuery;
}
```

Comment: i am curious if JQuery has anything to say about using JQuery.html() this way? Maybe it is not recommended or there is some other reason why the typescript definition is missing.

Comment: @mobal: You're quite right to wonder, [it's undocumented](http://api.jquery.com/html/). (TIL!) `html` is only *documented* to accept `string` and `function` (which is presumably why this is not in the ts file). It works (https://jsfiddle.net/vuop0e57/), and as far as I know it's always worked, but it's not *documented* behavior.